# What is the difference between cholesky in numpy and scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I use Cholesky decomposition to sample random variables from multi-dimension Gaussian, and calculate the power spectrum of the random variables. The result I get from `numpy.linalg.cholesky` always has higher power in high frequencies than from `scipy.linalg.cholesky`.

What are the differences between these two functions that could possibly cause this result? Which one is more numerically stable?

Here is the code I use:

```
n = 2000

m = 10000

c0 = np.exp(-.05*np.arange(n))

C = linalg.toeplitz(c0)

Xn = np.dot(np.random.randn(m,n),np.linalg.cholesky(C))

Xs = np.dot(np.random.randn(m,n),linalg.cholesky(C))

Xnf = np.fft.fft(Xn)

Xsf = np.fft.fft(Xs)

Xnp = np.mean(Xnf*Xnf.conj(),axis=0)

Xsp = np.mean(Xsf*Xsf.conj(),axis=0)
```

Comment: From the scipy faq [What is the difference between NumPy and SciPy?](http://new.scipy.org/faq.html#what-is-the-difference-between-numpy-and-scipy): "In any case, SciPy contains more fully-featured versions of the linear algebra modules, as well as many other numerical algorithms."  See also [Why both `numpy.linalg` and `scipy.linalg`? What’s the difference?](http://new.scipy.org/faq.html#why-both-numpy-linalg-and-scipy-linalg-what-s-the-difference).

Comment: @StevenRumbalski pls update the links as the pages are not available anymore.

Comment: @Rex5:  Comments cannot be edited after five minutes.  It's been six years.  The comment includes enough of a quote to be useful and searching on the text of the link will let you find it if you really want to.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski  Great ! thanks though !

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`scipy.linalg.cholesky` is giving you the upper-triangular decomposition by default, whereas `np.linalg.cholesky` is giving you the lower-triangular version.  From the docs for `scipy.linalg.cholesky`:

```
cholesky(a, lower=False, overwrite_a=False)
    Compute the Cholesky decomposition of a matrix.

    Returns the Cholesky decomposition, :math:`A = L L^*` or
    :math:`A = U^* U` of a Hermitian positive-definite matrix A.

    Parameters
    ----------
    a : ndarray, shape (M, M)
        Matrix to be decomposed
    lower : bool
        Whether to compute the upper or lower triangular Cholesky
        factorization.  Default is upper-triangular.
    overwrite_a : bool
        Whether to overwrite data in `a` (may improve performance).
```

For example:

```
>>> scipy.linalg.cholesky([[1,2], [1,9]])
array([[ 1.        ,  2.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  2.23606798]])
>>> scipy.linalg.cholesky([[1,2], [1,9]], lower=True)
array([[ 1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 1.        ,  2.82842712]])
>>> np.linalg.cholesky([[1,2], [1,9]])
array([[ 1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 1.        ,  2.82842712]])
```

If I modify your code to use the same random matrix both times and to use `linalg.cholesky(C,lower=True)` instead, then I get answers like:

```
>>> Xnp
array([ 79621.02629287+0.j,  78060.96077912+0.j,  77110.92428806+0.j, ...,
        75526.55192199+0.j,  77110.92428806+0.j,  78060.96077912+0.j])
>>> Xsp
array([ 79621.02629287+0.j,  78060.96077912+0.j,  77110.92428806+0.j, ...,
        75526.55192199+0.j,  77110.92428806+0.j,  78060.96077912+0.j])
>>> np.allclose(Xnp, Xsp)
True
```

Comment: is it possible to compute the upper-triangular with numpy's cholesky function? The official doc doesn't seem to help with this question (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.cholesky.html).